# Storing values instead of references in ArrayList

Tags: java, pointers, memory, jvm

I have a problem in my Java code for the past 4 days, and I can't, in the life of me, find the root cause of it.

Basically, I create an ArrayList of a list of Objects which have a list of objects as attributes. But when I try applying a method in the first element of the list, the other objects get updated as well!

Here's a basic overview of my object structure:

```
public class Matrix {
    public double[][] A;

    public Matrix(double[][] A) {
        this.A = A;
    }
}
public class Model {
    public Matrix M;

    public Model(Matrix M) {
        this.M = M;
    }

    public static Model(Model m) {
        // modifying model a bit
        return newModel;
    }
}

public class MyProgram {
    public ArrayList<Model> models;

    public main() {
        this.models = new ArrayList<Model>(NUM);
        Matrix A = randomMatrix();
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
            this.models.add(new Model(A));
        }
    }

    public otherMethod() {
        this.models.set(0, changeModel(this.models.get(0)));
    }
}
```

The problem is whenever I invoke the otherMethod, all the models in the list get changed as well!

Comment: And what goes wrong ? You didn't describe any particular issue / output problem ?

Comment: Java does exactly as you said. And you said that all your models should have the same `Matrix` in them (assuming that's what that comment about looping hides). So when you change `Matrix` in one `Model`, you change the same `Matrix` that's in all other models as well.

Comment: @TheophileDano I updated w/ the issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `clone` your `2-D array` not just assign it:

So instead of `this.A = A;`

You should use something like this for copying:

```
public static int[][] deepCopyIntMatrix(int[][] input) {
    if (input == null)
        return null;

    int[][] result = new int[input.length][];

    for (int r = 0; r < input.length; r++) {
        result[r] = input[r].clone();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: or use `System.arrayCopy`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, the issue was indeed about deep copy:

public class Matrix {
    public double[][] A;

```
public Matrix(double[][] A) {
    A = new double[n][m];
    for(int i=...)
         for(int j=...)
               this.A[i][j] = A[i][j];
}
```

And to add my matrices, I did this:

```
this.models.add(new Model(new Matrix(A.A))));
```

Comment: No. Please, this is not accurate. And the reason why I lost the three last days of work. The clone method only work for 1-D arrays apparently.